# Plugin Store install buttons are not visible

Tags: craft3, plugins

I'm just working on a dev site and my Plugin install buttons are gone. I'm not sure how long they've been gone either, I don't really know where to start to debug it.

No errors in the console and I have run `composer update` to make sure I'm all up to date, too.

Below is an image of where the 'install' button should be in the plugin store.

[image: Top corner of a plugin details (where button should be)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you have the [allowUpdates](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#allowupdates) config setting in your `config/general.php` file set to `false`.